# How to use context and useTheme in React Native class components in react native navigation v6?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I know useContext is not specifically for components due to functionality, but I am trying to use ThemeContext and I know there is a way around it here. I saw the documentation for it where they use a class component but still could not make much sense of it.

I have included a [snack example here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/dark-theme) where classComponent.js is what I want to implement. I would like it to render the same as Friends.js but using a **class component** rather than a **function**. In this same snack, I would like toggle.js to be a class component.

This is the code I am trying to replicate.

```
const Toggle = (props) => {
  const { setTheme, theme } = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setTheme(theme === DefaultTheme ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme)}>
```

and this is the code that I have that I am trying to implement the above code in.

```
export default class Toggle extends React.Component {
   //How can I set my state?
   state = {}
   render(){
      return(
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setTheme(theme === DefaultTheme ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme)}>
      );
   }
```

Comment: You can wrap your class component in a functional component that passes the theme state down as a prop.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we convert `toggle.js` to a `class component`. There are two things that we need to do and one of them is not obvious at all (and I do not know why this is necessary, but there is an old bug on GitHub which has no satisfying answer yet).

1. Move the creation of `ThemeContext` to its own file (I don't know why this is necessary; maybe because the export must be a `default export`?).
2. Bind the context in the class component using `static contextType = ThemeContext`

Thus, the following converts `toggle.js` to a class component.

**ThemeContext.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
const ThemeContext = React.createContext();
export default ThemeContext
```

**toggle.js**

```js
import ThemeContext from '../ThemeContext'

class Toggle extends React.Component {

  static contextType = ThemeContext

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
      const {theme, setTheme} = this.context 

       return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setTheme(theme === Light ? Dark : Light)}>
        <View style={{ height: 50, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white',fontSize: 20 }}>Toggle theme</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  }
}

export default Toggle;
```

Using the `useTheme` hook in a class component is not possible for obvious reasons. There is no alternative for class components.

The official way to solve this problem is to wrap the class component into a functional component and pass the `theme` from `useTheme` as a prop to the class component. This [is recommended in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-theme/).

I have renamed it to `Friends.js`.

```js
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

class Friends extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { theme } = this.props;

    return (
      /* I would like to be able to call colors.primary and colors.secondary here rather than green and grey */
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary}}>

          <View style={{ height: 100, width: 300, backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{color: "black",fontSize: 30 }}>Friends Screen</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <ClassComponent {...props} theme={theme} />;
}
```

Here is an [updated snack using class components](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/dark-theme-using-class-components).